# How to use dj-database-url while connecting with postgresql in heroku using python

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I'm here because I'm really really new with heroku-python-django-postgresql group. I have googled for a usage for dj-database-url and I don't understand why i have to use it when developing a python application that needs to connect with postgresql. I have added postgresql (dev version) as add-on to my application, but I don't know how to tell to the app that I want it to use my db.

so, the short question is, How do I indicate to dj-database-url that I want to use my database?

Thanks for your time and answers, I'll appreciate your help because this is very very urgent!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

dj-database-url is a utility to help you load your database into your dictionary from the DATABASE_URL environment variable. Heroku uses environment variables for your database and other addons. To begin using your database you'd simply use the below command to setup your DATABASES dictionary:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

And maybe stash DATABASE_URL in your virtualenv activate script.

Comment: How does one go about setting up their local development environment, so that the settings that heroku requires will work in the local environment?

Comment: If you run export DATABASE_URL=yourlocaloryourremotedburl then it should work the same as Heroku. Additionally if you use foreman which installs with the heroku toolbelt it will automatically export the values in a .env file.

Comment: Just a note. `default` keyword argument is optional. If you don't specify it, it looks for `DATABASE_URL` env variable by default.

Comment: Using this results in a build failure with the error 'NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined.'

Comment: just add something like DATABASES={} before it, that'll remove the "not defined" error.

Answer (score 1):

May be help for param in setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": dj_database_url.config(
        default="postgres://postgres:saleor@localhost:5432/saleor", conn_max_age=600
    )
}
```

"database url" in default string have the value
postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]

Answer (score -1):

Use pip module dj-dtabase-url. Add an environmental var with the name 'DATABASE_URL' and the value from the heroku db settings.

Important, to avoid the error 'NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined.'
You still have to leave for example the default DATABSE settings.

The complete code:

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Comment: Unnecessary duplication.