# settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Trying to do some testing on my Heroku Local Server (`http://0.0.0.0:8000/`) - the `index.html` loads correctly but when I navigate away (for example to `admin`) from that page I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 417, in login
    return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 90, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 64, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 135, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 101, in get_context_data
    current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts.py", line 13, in get_current_site
    return Site.objects.get_current(request)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 58, in get_current
    return self._get_site_by_id(site_id)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 30, in _get_site_by_id
    site = self.get(pk=site_id)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1200, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 246, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 210, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Programming/projects/anybody/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 159, in get_connection_params
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/login/
Exception Value: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME or OPTIONS['service'] value.
```

settings.DATABASES:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'vygr',
        'USER': 'x',
        'PASSWORD': 'x',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}

[...]
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
[...]
```

Comment: There is already an answer follow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868040/how-to-use-dj-database-url-while-connecting-with-postgresql-in-heroku-using-pyth/10869728

Comment: Okay, so what do you have `settings.DATABASES` set to? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris updated OP - thanks for feedback

Comment: Do you set `DATABASES` anywhere else in the file? Or modify it? Are you using `dj_database_url` or `django_on_heroku`?

Comment: Yes - according to my ``requirements.txt`` I am using: ``dj-database-url==0.5.0``, I also have ``django-heroku`` but not ``django_on_heroku``

Comment: `django-heroku` is deprecated. Do you have something like `django_heroku.settings(locals())` in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply! Yes I do - updated my OP.